# Headline: "Chemical Company could build a plant in Uzbekistan" vs "Chemical Company may build a plant in Uzbekistan"

Tags: modal-verbs

Let's say I want to write a news article about a chemical company that plans to build a new plant in Uzbekistan. Which modal verb should I use in the headline - **could** or **may**?

> Chemical Company **may** build a plant in Uzbekistan
>
> Chemical Company **could** build a plant in Uzbekistan

I googled for differences between "may" and "could" and [found this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might):

> The difference between *I could go the cinema* and *I might/may go to the cinema* is that the former is associated with reasoning about conditions or alternatives, whereas the latter is just a statement of possibility. The former statement informs us about a decision-making process going on inside the speaker, whereas the latter statement informs us that it is possible that the speaker will later be found at the cinema.

Does this mean that **may** would be more appropriate in my headline?

If I use **could**, would that imply that the company's decision to build the plant is conditional (that is, it depends on whether a condition or a set of conditions prove favorable to the plan)? That the company may be looking at some alternative plans, e.g. for building a plant in Kyrgyzstan or Kazakhstan?

Comment: I don't think you'd find **could** in many newspaper headlines.  At the **could** stage, it's not news yet :)   If they're actively considering building the plant in a particular location, **may** or **might** is how I'd say it. Once the decision is made, "ChemCo **to build** plant in ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check dictionary.com for different uses of "may" http://www.dictionary.com/browse/may?s=t

and "could" http://www.dictionary.com/browse/could?s=t

I believe that will give you a better idea of how you should use these verbs. 
Since you say that the company "plans to build a new plant in Uzbekistan", I'd use "may", instead of "could".  "May" implies possibility and/or opportunity, while "could" implies "conditional possibility", so your guess is correct.
I hope this helps.